# How to do check validation in the ajax code

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter

This is my view page code:
when i enter the order no some details is fetched from the table.

[image]

This second pic shows that it fetched the data and displayed in the view page:
i have used the ajax code to fetch the data.

[image]

Now what i have want is if enter the order no is 1 and save into the another table.
now again same page refresh the content if again enter the order no as 1 it should not be displayed in the view page and alert the msg in ajax .

My controller code:

```
public function DC_Entry_Insert(){
    $this->load->model('User_model');
    $result = $this->User_model->DC_insert($_POST);
}
```

My ajax code:

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#orderno').on('input change',function(){
         var orderno = $("#orderno").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>Inventory/Orderfetch",
        data: {
                orderno:orderno
        },
        datatype: 'json',   
        success: function (data) {
            $('#Product_Name_div').html(data); 
        }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

my model code:

```
function fetch_item($orderno){
 $this->db->where("orderno",$orderno);
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->join('item_master', 'item_master.id = order_item.itname', 'left');
  $this->db->from('order_item');
  $query_result = $this->db->get()->result();
  $output = '<center><table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-xxs" id="tb2">  

  <tbody>';            

      if($query_result !='false'){
       $i=0; 

foreach ($query_result as $key => $value) { 

$output .='<tr> 
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" id="remove"></span></a></td>
<td><input style="width:50px" name="sno[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'.$value->sno.'" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:250px" name="itemname[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" value="'.$value->itemname.'" ></td> 
<td><input style="width:80px" name="qty[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs qty" value="'.$value->qty.'" id="qty_'.$i.'" onchange="calculate('.$i.')"></td> 
<td><input style="width:90px" name="wgt[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
<td><input style="width:150px" name="desc[]" type="text" class="form-control input-xs" > </td> 
<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:18px;" class="addMore" title="Add More Person"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></td>
</tr>'; 
$i++;
}
$output .="</tbody>
</table></center>";
echo $output;
}
}
```

Comment: what.............?

Answer (score 0):

You can do validation before posting to server using javascript or you can do server side. A small example if your are sending data

```
data: {
            orderno:orderno
    }
```

Then you can check on your backend

```
    if($this->input->post('orderno')=='10){
    $flag='1';
    }else{
    $flag='1';
    }
return $flag;
```

then you can show it on html tag or you can show on javascript alert.